# Azure Web App on Linux bitbucket deployment failed

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-deployment-slots

Start from yesterday, I am not able to deploy any changes from bitbucket on Azure Web App on Linux. I tried with new slot, and I am getting the following errors, any advice from MS expert on solving this issue?

> Failed to set up deployment source for web app vivadetail, using Bitbucket. {"Code":"BadRequest","Message":"Repository 'UpdateSiteSourceControl' operation failed with System.Net.WebException: The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request.\r\n at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.EndGetResponse(IAsyncResult asyncResult)\r\n at System.Threading.Tasks.TaskFactory`1.FromAsyncCoreLogic(IAsyncResult iar, Func`2 endFunction, Action`1 endAction, Task`1 promise, Boolean requiresSynchronization)\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)\r\n at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n at Microsoft.Web.Hosting.Administration.SiteRepositoryProvider.TrackerContext.d__78.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)\r\n at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n at Microsoft.Web.Hosting.Administration.SiteRepositoryProvider.d__40.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)\r\n at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n at Microsoft.Web.Hosting.Administration.BitbucketV2SiteRepositoryProvider.d__6.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)\r\n at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n at Microsoft.Web.Hosting.Administration.WebCloudController.<>c__DisplayClass35e.<b__359>d__363.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)\r\n at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n at Microsoft.Web.Hosting.Administration.Csm.Common.Helpers.AsyncHelper.RunSync[TResult](Func`1 func)\r\n at Microsoft.Web.Hosting.Administration.WebCloudController.UpdateSiteSourceControl(String subscriptionName, String webspaceName, String name, SiteSourceControl siteSourceControl).","Target":null,"Details":[{"Message":"Repository 'UpdateSiteSourceControl' operation failed with System.Net.WebException: The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request.\r\n at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.EndGetResponse(IAsyncResult asyncResult)\r\n at System.Threading.Tasks.TaskFactory`1.FromAsyncCoreLogic(IAsyncResult iar, Func`2 endFunction, Action`1 endAction, Task`1 promise, Boolean requiresSynchronization)\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)\r\n at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n at Microsoft.Web.Hosting.Administration.SiteRepositoryProvider.TrackerContext.<GetResponseAsync>d__78.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)\r\n at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n at Microsoft.Web.Hosting.Administration.SiteRepositoryProvider.<GetSSHKey>d__40.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)\r\n at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n at Microsoft.Web.Hosting.Administration.BitbucketV2SiteRepositoryProvider.<UpdateSiteSourceControl>d__6.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)\r\n at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n at Microsoft.Web.Hosting.Administration.WebCloudController.<>c__DisplayClass35e.<<UpdateSiteSourceControl>b__359>d__363.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)\r\n at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n at Microsoft.Web.Hosting.Administration.Csm.Common.Helpers.AsyncHelper.RunSync[TResult](Func`1 func)\r\n at Microsoft.Web.Hosting.Administration.WebCloudController.UpdateSiteSourceControl(String subscriptionName, String webspaceName, String name, SiteSourceControl siteSourceControl)."},{"Code":"BadRequest"},{"ErrorEntity":{"ExtendedCode":"05007","MessageTemplate":"Repository '{0}' operation failed with {1}.","Parameters":["UpdateSiteSourceControl","System.Net.WebException: The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request.\r\n at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.EndGetResponse(IAsyncResult asyncResult)\r\n at System.Threading.Tasks.TaskFactory`1.FromAsyncCoreLogic(IAsyncResult iar, Func`2 endFunction, Action`1 endAction, Task`1 promise, Boolean requiresSynchronization)\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)\r\n at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n at Microsoft.Web.Hosting.Administration.SiteRepositoryProvider.TrackerContext.d__78.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)\r\n at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n at Microsoft.Web.Hosting.Administration.SiteRepositoryProvider.d__40.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)\r\n at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n at Microsoft.Web.Hosting.Administration.BitbucketV2SiteRepositoryProvider.d__6.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)\r\n at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n at Microsoft.Web.Hosting.Administration.WebCloudController.<>c__DisplayClass35e.<b__359>d__363.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)\r\n at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n at Microsoft.Web.Hosting.Administration.Csm.Common.Helpers.AsyncHelper.RunSync[TResult](Func`1 func)\r\n at Microsoft.Web.Hosting.Administration.WebCloudController.UpdateSiteSourceControl(String subscriptionName, String webspaceName, String name, SiteSourceControl siteSourceControl)"],"Code":"BadRequest","Message":"Repository 'UpdateSiteSourceControl' operation failed with System.Net.WebException: The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request.\r\n at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.EndGetResponse(IAsyncResult asyncResult)\r\n at System.Threading.Tasks.TaskFactory`1.FromAsyncCoreLogic(IAsyncResult iar, Func`2 endFunction, Action`1 endAction, Task`1 promise, Boolean requiresSynchronization)\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)\r\n at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n at Microsoft.Web.Hosting.Administration.SiteRepositoryProvider.TrackerContext.<GetResponseAsync>d__78.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)\r\n at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n at Microsoft.Web.Hosting.Administration.SiteRepositoryProvider.<GetSSHKey>d__40.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)\r\n at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n at Microsoft.Web.Hosting.Administration.BitbucketV2SiteRepositoryProvider.<UpdateSiteSourceControl>d__6.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)\r\n at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n at Microsoft.Web.Hosting.Administration.WebCloudController.<>c__DisplayClass35e.<<UpdateSiteSourceControl>b__359>d__363.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)\r\n at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n at Microsoft.Web.Hosting.Administration.Csm.Common.Helpers.AsyncHelper.RunSync[TResult](Func`1 func)\r\n at Microsoft.Web.Hosting.Administration.WebCloudController.UpdateSiteSourceControl(String subscriptionName, String webspaceName, String name, SiteSourceControl siteSourceControl)."}}],"Innererror":null}

Comment: Linux App Service instances experienced a regression/outage of the SCM functionality (including source control) on all sites yesterday. Can you try again today? If it's still not working, please share your site name, privately (https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Reporting-your-site-name-without-posting-it-publicly) if you like.

Comment: Thank you, it's working now.

Comment: Actually, it's not fully solved. I am having error in deployment.sh script. Is there any example out there I need to follow? I am deploying a simple nodejs with angularjs frontend which is using bower install - which does not work..

Also, i have identified the continuous deployment doesn't work, which may be due to the deploy.sh script.

Comment: Please open a new question with more detail.

Comment: @nlawalker The service seems unstable. Now, I am getting some unknown error at the end of the deployment. please check vivamobile-2.azurewebsites.net for your reference.

Comment: If you could, please post a thread on https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/azure/en-US/home?forum=windowsazurewebsitespreview to continue this conversation; this forum is not a good fit for it.